# Jhipster copying the war file to tomcat 8 webapp gives index.html

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jhipster

built jhipster by mvn clean package -Pprod
deployed .war.original to webapps

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path index.html does not start with a "/" character
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getRequestDispatcher(ApplicationContext.java:454) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getRequestDispatcher(ApplicationContextFacade.java:221) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getRequestDispatcher(Request.java:1371) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getRequestDispatcher(RequestFacade.java:613) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.30]
        at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRequestDispatcher(ServletRequestWrapper.java:297) ~[servlet-api.jar:3.1.FR]
        at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestWrapper.getRequestDispatcher(RequestWrapper.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getRequestDispatcher(ServletRequestWrapper.java:297) ~[servlet-api.jar:3.1.FR]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.getRequestDispatcher(InternalResourceView.java:223) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:148) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1243) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) ~[spring-webmvc

Comment: Please describe your problem. Do you expect to have a context path or nto? How did you rename your war file as ROOT.war or did you configure the context root in conf/server.xml to use your war file? Have you read this: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/2870

Comment: fixed. i forgot to commit .bowerrc file which was causing that issue